# Not able to create a new USQL Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to create a U-SQL Project from Visual Studio. I am not able to create one. Here is the link for error message I receive.

[image]

**Note:** I have already installed the .NET SDK

Comment: That image is far too small to be readable. We find text easier to read anyway - please add the text in that page in a formatted block.

Comment: Also please note that the first two lines tell you that you should be reporting this error to a specific email address. Did you do that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio?  My understanding is that you need to have this installed before you can create a U-SQL Project.
The tools can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504